# Ckeditor Cursor position issue

Tags: ckeditor

Creating some predefined html template to be inserted on instance ready of the ckeditor. Place the cursor on the created element but the cursor position moves to the top of the template sometimes. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code you have created so far.

Comment: Hi Chris Please find my piece of code which have been created as a predefined template
 <test lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"> 
<testhead></testhead> 
<testbody>
<section>
<main>
<section>
<header>
 <div>
  <h1></h1>
 </div>
</header>
<main>
 <p></p>
</main>
</section>
</main>
</section> 
</testbody> 
</test>
I have provide css before content for the empty tags and when i place the cursor     inside the h1 sometimes it is moving to the top of my template and sometimes it is working correctly. Kinldy suggest on this